# Java - Comparing Strings which are numbers

Tags: java, file

How to compare String which are numbers?

I have Strings saved in file:

```
"2000 12 7 0 2 -3.0"
"2000 7 7 0 2 -4.0"
"2013 7 23 20 59 25.5"
```

First five values are date **(year, month, day, hour, minute)**. I need to sort them **chronologically**.

Here is my code:

```
 class Task3 {

    BufferedWriter writer;
    BufferedReader reader;
    int licznik = 0;



    Task3() throws IOException {
        this.writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("c:\\zadanie.txt"));
        this.reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("c:\\zadanie.txt"));

    }

    public void WriteMeasur(Measur measur) throws IOException{

       //licznik++;
        writer.write(measur.toString());
        writer.newLine();
    }

    public void WriteChrono(Measur measur) throws IOException{
        List<String> lista = new ArrayList<>();

        String line;        
        while((line = reader.readLine()) != null){
            lista.add(line);            
        }
    }
}

class Time implements Serializable{
    int year, month, day, hour, minute;

    Time(int r, int m, int d, int h, int min){
        if(r <= 2014 && r > 1990)
            this.year = r;
        if(m <= 12)
            this.month = m;
        if(d <= 30 || (m == 2 && d < 29))
            this.day = d;
        if(h <= 24)
            this.hour = h;
        if(min <= 60)
            this.minute = min;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString(){
        return String.valueOf(year) + " " + String.valueOf(month) +  " " +String.valueOf(day) + " " +String.valueOf(hour) +  " " +String.valueOf(minute);

    }
}
class Measur implements Serializable{
    Time time;
    double temp;

    Measur(Time czas, double temp){
        this.time = czas;
        this.temp = temp;

    }

    @Override
    public String toString(){
        return time.toString() + " " +String.valueOf(temp);

    }

}

public class Main{
    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException{

        //Argumenty klasy czas: rok, miesiac, dzien, godzina, minuty
        // Metody inicjujace klase czas

        Time czas_1 = new Time(2013,7,23,20,59);
        Time czas_3 = new Time(2000,07,7,25,2);
        Time czas_2 = new Time(2000,12,7,25,2);

        // Metody inicjujace klase pomiar

        Measur pomiar_1 = new Measur(czas_1, 25.5);
        Measur pomiar_2 = new Measur(czas_2, -3);
        Measur pomiar_3 = new Measur(czas_3, -4);


        Task3 zad3 = new Task3();

        zad3.WriteMeasur(pomiar_1);
        zad3.WriteMeasur(pomiar_2);
        zad3.WriteMeasur(pomiar_3);
        zad3.writer.close();

    }
}
```

I have no idea how to sort it. I wanted use `Collections.sort()`, but in Strings 2000 12 is smaller then 2000 7.

Any advice?

Thanks!

Comment: you must take a look at SimpleDateFormat - http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Comment: You should implement a [Comparator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html), perhaps with a [GregorianCalendar](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/GregorianCalendar.html#GregorianCalendar%28int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure this is a good idea or not.  But you could use [`Collections.sort`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List,%20java.util.Comparator%29) support of [`Comparator`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) to customise the way in which values are compared while they are been sorted and [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) to convert the value to a `Date` value which can then be compared directly...for example...

```
List<String> values = new ArrayList<String>(25);
values.add("2013 7 23 20 59 25.5");
values.add("2000 12 7 0 2 -3.0");
values.add("2000 7 7 0 2 -4.0");

Collections.sort(values, new Comparator<String>() {
    private SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy MM dd");
    @Override
    public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
        int result = -1;
        try {
            Date d1 = sdf.parse(o1);
            Date d2 = sdf.parse(o2);
            result = d1.compareTo(d2);
        } catch (ParseException exp) {
            exp.printStackTrace();
        }
        return result;
    }
});

for (String value : values) {
    System.out.println(value);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Create yourself a personal `MyDate` Object that is passed a `String` in its constructor and parses that string to initialize your `year, month, day, hour, min, sec` fields.

Then write a custom `Comparator` for your class `MyDateComparator` and code your logic for sorting.

Store your `MyDate` objects not `String` in your `List` and use `Collections.sort(myDateList, new MyDateComparator())

See [The Ordering Collections Java Tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/order.html) for tips on how to use `Comparators`

Answer (score 1):

Split the string with space as delimiter, convert into integer array and then sort?

Comment: Ok so i have tried this and i'm getting error: "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "2013723205925"" Why? To big number for int, or what?

It is happening when i'm split all line and parse it to int.
Thanks